# Precedence of operators in C

Tags: operators, operator-precedence

I know that suffix and postfix increment (decrement) have higher predence vs comparison (==) in C.

But I'm running into confusion right now, if I have 2 conditional loops like `while (0 != i--)`
 and `while (0!= --i)` , so what is the difference there? Because due to precedence the decrement should always be executed first then do the comparision?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`i--` "uses" the value of `i` and then decrements it.

`--i` decrements i and then "uses" the value of `i`.

So if `i=4` then `while(0 != i--){ printf("%d\n", i); }` would show 3 (because i is now decremented), 2, 1, 0 (because i was 1 when the check was done).

In the `while(0 != --i) { printf("%d\n", i); } you'd get 3 (i is still decremented), 2, 1 but not 0.`i` was 0 when the check was performed because it was PREdecremented.

Comment: So the precedence of operators don't really matter here? What if I intend to put --i and i-- inside brackets ( ) ?

Comment: Try it and find out! `i--` means "use i then decrement it". `--i` means "decrement i then use it" - so the value of `i` you see in each case is different.